# extracting matched strings in text file

Tags: regex, matlab

I have a data file look like;

```
***************************
***************************
***************************  (header part)
*  2004 11  8  0  0  0.00000000
P  1  1000.4545  211.1214  54.5545 
P  3  5400.5454  1005.4545 -452.4899
P  4  ........   .........   .......
P  5  ........   .........  ........
.
.
*  2004 11  8  0 15  0.00000000
P  1  1085.4545  200.1214  54.5545 
P  3  5405.5454  1105.4545 -452.4899
P  4  ........   .........   .......
P  5  ........   .........   .......
```

There are several "P  1", "P  3" and so on in the text file. I need to define all "P  [0-9]"'s numeric rows like;

```
P_1=[1000.4545 211.1214 54.5545;1085.4545 200.1214 54.5545];
p_3=[5400.5454 1005.4545 -452.4899;5405.5454 1105.4545 -452.4899];
```

Which codes give me this flexibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regular expression with `regexp`.
If you have your data in the file data.txt

```
txt = fileread('data.txt')
parts = regexp(txt,'P\s*1\s*(\S*)\s*(\S*)\s*(\S*)','tokens')
P_1 = [reshape(str2double([parts{:}]),3,[])]'
```

If you want to do this in a loop for all 9 P's I would suggest to use a cell array rather than `P_1` `P_2` etc. You can build the expression for `regexp` inside the loop quite simply:

```
for i = 1:9
    exp = ['P\s*', num2str(i), '\s*(\S*)\s*(\S*)\s*(\S*)'];
    parts = regexp(txt,exp,'tokens')
    P{i} = [reshape(str2double([parts{:}]),3,[])]';
end
```

Comment: these codes don't give the correct result. Is there any way I can send or attach the original data file?

Comment: No I will not do your work for you. What did you get vs. what did you expect ? Did you try reading about the functions I used ?

Comment: first part of your code gives P_1=[1000.4545 54.5545 200.1214; 211.1214 1085.4545 54.5545] but it should be like; P_1=[1000.4545 211.1214 54.5545; 1085.4545 200.1214 54.5545]; Could you explain what caused this difference?

Comment: Try `P_1 = [reshape(str2double([parts{:}]),3,[])]'` instead. Make same change inside the for loop